# SBJSON Float in NSDictionary written to NSString incorrect

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary, sbjson

I'm using SBJSON in a project and I'm trying to build a json string from a dictionary.

Here's what's going on, I'm putting floats as NSNumbers into a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* tempdic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
tempdic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:productId, @"productId", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:quantity], @"aantal", price, @"price" , nil];
        [orders addObject:tempdic];
NSDictionary* json = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: orders, @"order", message, @"message", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:orderprice], @"totalPrice",dueDate,@"dueDate", nil];
```

And then to finally write it as a json string, I tried these three.

1)

```
NSData* jsonData = [writer dataWithObject:json];
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

2)

```
NSString* jsonString = [json JSONRepresentation];
```

3)

```
NSString* jsonString = [writer stringWithObject:json];
```

Each of these changes 0.95 into 0.95000000000000034355 or even worse 0.949999999999999992344 or something alike.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the basic problem with float values. You can't store values which can't be represented by the sum of the power of `2`. Thus resulting with the approximate value to your floating point.

e.g. `1.25` can be easily represented as sum of power of `2` 
i.e.  `1*2^0 +1*2^-2` but if you are going to represent `1.33` as sum of power of `2` then the resultant would be `1*2^0 + 1*2^-2 + 1*2^-4 + 1*2^-8 + 1*2^-9 ....`

Just read [**Representable numbers, conversion and rounding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) on wiki.
And you can check your floating point representation [**using online tool**](http://www.binaryconvert.com).

Comment: when you again covert back it to floating point it will show you `.95`  or while you convert it to string use %.2f so that it will give you the 2 digits after decimal point

Comment: the json file is sent to a server where it is parsed again. So the server would have to correctly round it off? I just wondered if there was a way to do it in the app.

Comment: These things will always be there so no need of doing anything. Just pass these values as it is. Suppose your server/app converts your string `0.949999999999999992344 ` to `0.95` as this is a float values so your server/app will store these values again to float variable thus resulting in same value `0.949999999999999992344`.

Comment: Moreover these precession loss is so small that it won't affect your data. Unless you are keep on multiplying resulting your precision loss more and more.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic problem with floating point numbers. You can, however, use `NSDecimalNumber` rather than `NSNumber` to get higher precision (at the cost of lower *range* of numbers).